# Output unformated?

Tags: python

I am newbie in Python. Was doing an exercise in LearnPythonTheHardWay by Mr. Zed Shaw.
I have been stuck with this problem

here is the code:

```
age=input("How old are you?");
height=input("How tall are you?");
weight=input("How much do you weight?");
print ("age = %r height = %r weight = %r" %(age,height,weight))
```

And its output:

```
D:\Python>python sample1.py
How old are you?22
How tall are you?182
How much do you weight?178
age = '22\r' height = '182\r' weight = '178\r'
```

I am not understanding, how is that, I am getting "\r" with the output?
Please help !!!

Comment: Oh noes, semi-colons in Python code!

Comment: Incidentally, this is only true with Python 3.x. On Python 2.7, `input()` correctly parses `'\r\n'` as newline, not just `'\n'`. Anyone knows why?

Comment: while %r and not %s or, even better, use string's format() method?

Comment: @NullUserException, I actually didnt use semi-colons, but when was trying out with different possible errors that i could make, i saw semi-colons was accepted!! Yea but, ill not use it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using Python 3. In Python 3, the `input()` function returns a *string* which is what you typed at the prompt. In Python 2, the `input()` function returns an evaluated *expression*, which in your case if you type a number would be an integer.

You have three basic choices:

- Find a tutorial that uses Python 3
- Install Python 2 for use with your current tutorial
- Simulate Python 2 `input()` by using `eval(input(...))`

Comment: ... or `int(input(...))` in this case.

Comment: But where does that carriage return come from, if you type something in Python3 (or 2) on windows and hit enter you don't get any \r nor \n.

Comment: @Greg, Could you suggest me any good Python3.0 books? Grateful to you if i get it :). Also, which is the best way to get the input??

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: I'm not quite sure. I don't have a Windows machine handy to try at the moment, and all my other machines didn't include any newline on input.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that on some systems a `newline` character (the way the language understands that you've hit the `enter` key) is by the appearance of either `\n` (more popularly called the newline character) or `\r` (more popularly called the return character) or both.

Some time in the history of development of various operating systems, some took to `\n` and some to `\r` (and some in fact took to using both i.e. `\r\n`). This is why on some really low-level C programs, you have to check for `CR` and `LF`, which, by the way, was inspired by the `carriage return` and `line feed` operations on typewriters.

So, what you really need to do is remove both `\r` and `\n` (whichever are present) from the end of each line.

However, it may not always be clear which are used, but luckily python gives you a way to deal with that, namely the `strip` function, which handles all possible combinations of `\r` and `\n`.

Hope this helps